# Writing a line break in php

Tags: php

i am making a website later to be released on the world  but i had a form i was going to send and then a php script to process said form but after i have the script writing to a .txt file i cant figure out how to get it to put in a a page break or enter so that multiple form entries are not on the same line does anyone know how to get around this? php code looks like this

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'] ;
$email=$_POST['mail'];
$comment = $_POST['message'];
//the data
$data = "$username | $email | $comment ";
//open the file and choose the mode

$fh = fopen("comments.txt", "a");

fwrite($fh, $data,);
//close the file
fclose($fh);
print "Message Sent Successfully! Hit the back button for more skubduger.tk";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//the data
$data = "$username | $email | $comment \n";
```

Comment: tried this but it just put a space and then writes the next submission. could there be something i did wrong when i installed php

Answer (score 0):

Since you're writing to a file, you'll need to add the new-line character, `\n` to the end of your data. You can do it when you create the variable, or when you're writing it to the file (or anywhere in-between really):

```
$data = "$username | $email | $comment \n";
```

or use `sprintf()` to make it a little cleaner (at least, cleaner to me =P):

```
$data = sprintf("%s | %s | %s \n", $username, $email, $comment);
```

or append it directly to `$data` when you're writing it to the file:

```
fwrite($fh, $data . "\n");
```

If you want it to be Windows-specific, you'll want the carriage-return + line-feed, `\r\n`.

Comment: for some strange reason none of the suggestions worked but the \r\n dont really know why but i am happy now and thank you for your expertise

Comment: @user3466945 If the `\r\n` worked, that most likely means you're on Windows and you're trying to read the file in Notepad; on Linux or in a different text editor on Windows (such as Notepad++), a single `\n` would do the trick too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP_EOL constant instead of guessing what to use \r\n or \n. It would work on any platform.

```
$data = "$username | $email | $comment ".PHP_EOL;
```